# IOUtils.write creates new file but doesn't write data

Tags: java

using IOUtils.write to write a string to a file

```
    try {
        IOUtils.write("test", new FileWriter(configFile));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where configfile is the location of the configuration file ("./resources/config.json")
This seems to delete the file and replace it with a file that has no contents.

no exceptions are thrown either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to close the stream after use, else the data might not be written to the file.

```
 FileWriter fw=null;
 try {
    fw= new FileWriter(configFile);
    IOUtils.write("test",fw);
    }catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }finally
   {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(fw);
   }
```

Comment: I would provide to use IOUtils.closeQuietly(fw) method. Adding closeQuietly() in your finally-block just ensures the close, e.g. when the flush failed and close was not called in try-block.

Comment: Yes closing of streams should always be written in the `finally` , this ensures that the `close()` is always executed. Besides exception in `try`, it will also ensure `close()` is executed against unsuspected returns or breaks from the `try` or `catch`

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the writer, or use try with resources. Otherwise everything might not be flushed to disk:

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(configFile)) {
    IOUtils.write("test", fw);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
FileWriter fw = null;
try {
    fw  = new FileWriter(configFile);
    IOUtils.write("test", fw);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(fw != null)
        fw.close();
}
```